# ejabberd and riak integration configuration

Tags: configuration, ejabberd, riak

I am trying to use ejabberd and also use Riak as the backend database for it.  I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/) to the best of my ability but I keep error messages like unrecognized string or something.

So I basically set:

```
default_db: riak
riak_server: "69.1.1.1"
riak_port: 8087
```

Which is what it looks like the instructions say to do but it never freaking works and the documentation and examples for ejabberd are just terrible.  They are outdated in several places and just missing or not intended for any sort of quickstart. I've spent the past 2 days trying to get this to work. I spun up an ejabberd server and Riak server with very little trouble but integrating the two is like pulling teeth!  Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: why you are using  this line - default_db: riak ?  remove this line from configuration  file.

Answer (score 0):

In ejabberd.yml write the following lines only-

```
riak_server: "192.168.1.107"  ## localhost or whatever your ip
riak_port: 8087
```

[Here is riak configuration example for ejabberd modules](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/test/ejabberd_SUITE_data/ejabberd.yml)

Comment: Thanks so much for responding!  I am still a bit confused unfortunately.  
So are you saying that I should not have default_db: riak in my configuration? Except for that, your example and mine are the same. For the linked example, do I need to set the db_type for each module or does that example merely give me the options of doing that?

Comment: ejabberd provides flexibility of different database for different module so set  the db_type for each module  as I know.